# CSS/Jquery Drop-down menu doesn't work as intended

Tags: html, css

Been trying to follow a guide about how you make a simple drop down menu with html/css/jquery but the end result is totally messed up and I simply have no clue why.

[image]

For some reason, there this empty space to the left of the drop-down menu that I do not know why it is there or how I get rid of it... Help would be much appreciated.

HMTL:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>



<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">First </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Third </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Fifth</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Fifth</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="clr"></div>




<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.clr {clear: both:}

ul {
   list-style: none;
}
ul li {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
ul li a {
   width: 118px;
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #1787cf;
   background: #fff;
}
ul li a:hover {
   background: #1787cf;
   color: #fff;
}
li ul {
   display: none;
}
li ul li {
   float: left;
}

li:hover > ul {

   position: absolute;
   top: 52px;
   left: 0;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
li ul li:hover > ul {

   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 120px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

JQuery:

```
(function(){


$('ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
    }, function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp().css('display', 'none');
});
})();
```

Comment: Try setting `padding-left: 0` on the child lists.

Comment: You could probably get away with use CSS3 instead of javascript, using `height: 0` and `height: auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the margin and padding on the children items. Try this:

```css
ul li ul,
ul li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UL and LI have [default margin and padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) that you haven't removed. I'm assuming you don't want it on parent or children.

```
ul, li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
    ul li ul, ul li ul li{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
```

Here, is the updated fiddle for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/5Z2QV/23/